# How to add dictionary values with similar key values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Sample:

```
d={}
d['rb2401_long'] = {'Position': 20, 'LongFrozen': 1, 'ShortFrozen': 5}
d['yd_rb2401_long'] = {'Position': 10, 'LongFrozen': 2, 'ShortFrozen': 3}
d['rb2401_short'] = {'Position': 30, 'LongFrozen': 10, 'ShortFrozen': 6}
d['yd_rb2401_short'] = {'Position': 15, 'LongFrozen': 8, 'ShortFrozen': 2}
d['sc2311_long'] = {'Position': 200, 'LongFrozen': 0, 'ShortFrozen': 50}
d['yd_sc2311_long'] = {'Position': 100, 'LongFrozen': 20, 'ShortFrozen': 30}
d['sc2311_short'] = {'Position': 300, 'LongFrozen': 100, 'ShortFrozen': 60}
d['yd_sc2311_short'] = {'Position': 150, 'LongFrozen': 80, 'ShortFrozen': 20}
```

The value of `d['rb2401_long_result']` is the sum of `d['rb2401_long']` and `d['yd_rb2401_long']`.

The value of `d['rb2401_short_result']` is the sum of `d['rb2401_short']` and `d['yd_rb2401_short']`

Expected:

```
d['rb2401_long_result']={'Position': 30, 'LongFrozen': 3, 'ShortFrozen': 8}
```

My method is:

```
r={}
for key,values in d.items():
    rk=key.split('yd_')[-1]
    if rk in r:
        r[rk]['Position']+=values['Position']
        r[rk]['LongFrozen']+=values['LongFrozen']
        r[rk]['ShortFrozen']+=values['ShortFrozen']
    else:
        r[rk]=values
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Stackoverflow is here to help you figure out problems with your code, so: where is your code? Because [SO is _not_ a code writing service](/help/on-topic) where you say what you need and others write it for you =)

Comment: If it's supposed to be the sum of two other values, then **do that**.  Get the two other `Position` values and add them together.  Get the two other `LongFrozen` values and add them together.  etc etc.  What is the difficulty?  Do you not know how to pull values from a dict and add them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking *r* for *rk*, just apply the value of the *"yd_"* prefixed *key*.

```py
r = { }
for k, v in d.items():
    if k.startswith('yd_'):
        for k1, v1 in v.items(): d[k[3:]][k1] += v1
        r.update({k[3:] + '_result': d[k[3:]]})
```

Ouput

```
('rb2401_long_result', {'Position': 30, 'LongFrozen': 3, 'ShortFrozen': 8})
('rb2401_short_result', {'Position': 45, 'LongFrozen': 18, 'ShortFrozen': 8})
('sc2311_long_result', {'Position': 300, 'LongFrozen': 20, 'ShortFrozen': 80})
('sc2311_short_result', {'Position': 450, 'LongFrozen': 180, 'ShortFrozen': 80})
```